# React Navigation: Transparent header has no height

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

If I set `headerTransparent: true` the other content which was usually rendered below it moves underneath it. How can I avoid that?

My code:

```
export class RegisterScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: strings.header,
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTransparent: true,
  };
  render() {
    return <Display onSignUpPressed={() => {}} onHelpPressed={() => {}} />;
  }
}
```

With transparent header (it overlaps :( ):

[image]

Without transparent header:

[image]

I'd like to have the content aligned as if the header had a height. So I want the content to be like in the second picture, but with a transparent header like in the first.

Comment: Add a <View style={styles.statusBar} /> where style can be: statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#C2185B",
    width: "100%",
    height: Constants.statusBarHeight
  }

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/855#issuecomment-301671395

Comment: try adding headerBackground

Answer (score 5):

You can now use the `headerStyle` property to give your header a transparent background, while keeping its height:

```js
static navigationOptions = {
    title: strings.header,
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
  };
```

Comment: I have tried the other options mentioned here but only this works without much work.

Answer (score 3):

Header overlaps with the content underneath if `headerTransparent: true` is set. You need to manually add a top margin or padding according to your situation to your content if you dont want it overlapped. React Navigation won't do it automatically but it provides a hook that gets header height

```
import { useHeaderHeight } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

Now, you can get the height in your component like this:

```
const headerHeight = useHeaderHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give you screen component a top padding equivalent to the height of the header ,

Answer (score 0):

On React Native v6.x

Instead of doing

```
screenOptions={{headerTransparent: true}}
```

You can apply it in the backgroundColor in the header style like so

```
screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent';
    }
}}
```

This is if you wanna keep the padding

Answer (score 0):

It's a little confusing but you need this point
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headersearchbaroptions

you need add to your page ScrollView or Flatlist param:
contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic". Even you don't use `searchBar`.

`headerSearchBarOptions Options to render a native search bar on iOS. Search bars are rarely static so normally it is controlled by passing an object to headerSearchBarOptions navigation option in the component's body. You also need to specify contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic" in your ScrollView, FlatList etc. If you don't have a ScrollView, specify headerTransparent: false.`

Answer (score -2):

Add headerBackground to navigationOptions like this

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: strings.header,
    headerTitleStyle: { color: '#fff' },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTransparent: true,
    headerBackground: Platform.select({
        ios: <BlurView style={{ flex: 1 }} intensity={98} />,
        android: (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)' }} />
    ),
  }),
};
```

Comment: That seems only like a workaround especially since you still render something with intensity 98

Comment: @J.Hesters, According to react navigation documentation you have to provide headerStyle or headerBackground, when you using headerTransparent: true. Check this -  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#headertransparent

Answer (score -2):

We can make transparent header with the help of

> headerTransparent: true

but with this we also need to give headerStyle like this to make transparent header.

```
static navigationOptions = {
headerTransparent: true,
headerStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 0 }
};
```

In my case I make it possible by giving this style to my header.

> style:{ position: 'absolute', backgroundColor: 'transparent', zIndex:
>   100, top: 0, left: 0, right: 0}